# How to simply vertical center a div with text beside another div with buttons with Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I just want to perfectly vertical center a text in a `div` beside two `buttons` in other `div` on a same line.

My text have `text-left` class and my buttons have `text-right`.

I searched all afternoon, maybe i need another look...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-left" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      A simple text here.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
      <button name="spy" class="btn btn-info">Espionner</button>
      <button name="attack" class="btn btn-danger">Attaquer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7ve3re24/)

Should i use something else than only Twitter Bootstrap's classes ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by `beside can you explain?`

Comment: I want to show a text on the left and buttons on the right on the same line. You can take a look to my JSFiddle to understand :) The text isn't vertically centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether you want something like this--

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7ve3re24/2/)

```css
.col-xs-6  h5 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 text-left" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray; margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
    
      
     <h5>
     
     A simple text here. </h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
      <button name="spy" class="btn btn-info">Espionner</button>
      <button name="attack" class="btn btn-danger">Attaquer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I'll using your method to solve my problem. Regards :)

Comment: I solved my problem with this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ve3re24/9/)

Comment: Great looks perfect!

Comment: `vertical-align: middle`; and `display: inline-block;` are important ? i get the same result to simply put `h5` class in my div's text

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 text-left" style="padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray; margin-top: 10px;">
   <form  class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
        <label class="span1" >A simple text here.</label>
         <button name="spy" class="btn btn-info">Espionner</button>
      <button name="attack" class="btn btn-danger">Attaquer</button>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to vertically aligned All three component then you should use from-inline class and Html look like this.